# Tomcat server port number vs MySqlWorkbench port number

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, tomcat, jdbc

I try to create a connection between the database `hospitalm` and java code.

I am using eclipse as my IDE. I created a project named `testproject`.

I added external JAR file mysql-connector-java from properties-> build path-> libraries.

The java code that I wrote to create the connection is

```
package testproject;
import java.sql.*;
public class democlass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection
       con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080/hospitalm","root","1234");
        System.out.println("Connection was established");
        con.close();
        
    }

}
```

The output should be `Connection was established`.

I got the ouptput:

[image]

I have a doubt which one should be the localhost port number for the line  `Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080/hospitalm","root","1234");`

I got a different localhost port number while starting the mysql.

[image]

Here the port number is 3306

So I changed the port number on my above code. But the error was same.

I would like to share the screenshot of my tomcat server as well

[image]

Additionally the databases on the mysqlworkbench are

[image]

I can not figure out what's wrong with my program? Why it can not create a connection with the database?

Thank you.

Comment: a) mysql listens on port 3306.  b) public static void main - not a web application

Comment: Okay. So what will be the port number? 3306?

Comment: If you this java file as a normal java application in eclipse and connect to port 3306 it should work.

Comment: No it is not working. I created the java file under src/main/java -> testproject-> democlass.java. The path can be seen from the above picture. But even if I give the port number 3306 it did not work.